# How to separate comma delimited values without using vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, file-handling

I'm working on ATM machine code in C++. I know it is best to use a binary file and classes so that each account has exact same size in file even if it is empty. I'm looking for something very very simple.

I'm having problem with parsing comma delimited values in `.txt` file. Sometime I get values, sometime I get just the first value. I have spent days to figure out it's solution. I have searched the internet and stackoverflow almost every answer used vectors or other stuff.

I didn't use `strcmp` for array comparison instead created my own function to compare character to character.

From the look of the code, it seems I have done a lot just a little push is required. Kindly have a look at my code and let me know where am I wrong. I want to eliminate semantic error! And to have the following code amended for the achievement of expected results.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void checkBalance();
void createAccount();
void deposit();
void withdraw();
void transfer();
void login();
void mainScreen();
void menuScreen();
// For file handling
void saveAccountToFile();
bool checkAccountExists(char*);
void loadAccount(char *);
void loadBeneficiary(char*);

bool compare(char *, char *);

const char * FILE_NAME = "accounts.txt";

char username[50];
char pin[5];
double balance = 0.0;

// Beneficiary Variables

char b_username[50];
char b_pin[5];
double b_balance = 0.0;

void menuScreen()
{
    char opt;
    do {
    system("cls");
    cout << "\n\n\t\t CMD - ATM";
    cout << "\n\n\tMENU";
    cout << "\n\n\t01. Check Balance";
    cout << "\n\n\t02. Withdraw";
    cout << "\n\n\t03. Deposite";
    cout << "\n\n\t04. Transfer to Another account";
    cout << "\n\n\t05. Logout";
    opt = _getch();
    switch (opt)
    {
    case '1':
        checkBalance();
        break;
    case '2':
        withdraw();
        break;
    case '3':
        deposite();
        break;
    case '4':
        transfer();
    case '5':
        cout << "\n\nThanks for using CMD ATM. Press any key to exit...";
        _getch();
        exit(1);
    default:
        cout << "\a\n\nIncorrect input. Press any key to try agian!";
        _getch();
    }
} while (opt != '5');
}

void mainScreen() 
{
char opt;
do {
    system("cls");
    cout << "\n\n\t\t CMD - ATM";
    cout << "\n\n\tMENU";
    cout << "\n\n\t01. Create Account";
    cout << "\n\n\t02. Login";
    cout << "\n\n\t03. Exit";
    opt = _getch();
    switch (opt)
    {
    case '1':
        createAccount();
        break;
    case '2':
        login();
        break;
    case '3':
        exit(1);
    default:
        cout << "\a\n\nIncorrect input. Press any key to try agian!";
        _getch();
    }
} while (opt != '3');
}

void saveAccountToFile() {

ofstream outFile;
outFile.open(FILE_NAME, ios::app);
if (outFile.is_open()) {
        outFile << username << ',' <<
            pin << ',' << balance << "\n";
}
outFile.close();
}

bool checkAccountExists(char * userName)
{   
int i = 0;

char temp[50] = {'0'};
ifstream inFile;
string line;
inFile.open(FILE_NAME);

if (inFile.is_open()) {
    while (getline(inFile, line)) {
        stringstream ss(line);
        string value;
        while (getline(ss, value, ',')) {
            if (i == 0) {
                strcpy(temp,value.c_str());
                if(compare(userName, temp)){
                    cout << "closing";
                    getchar();
                    inFile.close();
                    return true;
                }
                i = 1;
            }
            else if (i == 1) {
                i = 2;
            }
            else if (i == 2) {
                i = 0;
            }       
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
}
return false;
}


void loadAccount(char * userName)
{

int i = 0;
ifstream inFile;
string line;
inFile.open(FILE_NAME);

if (inFile.is_open()) {
    while (getline(inFile, line)) {
        stringstream ss(line);
        string value;
        while (getline(ss, value, ',')) {
            if (i == 0) {
                strcpy(username, value.c_str());
                i = 1;
            }
            else if (i == 1) {
                strcpy(pin, value.c_str());
                i = 2;
            }
            else if (i == 2) {
                balance = atof(value.c_str());
                i = 0;
            }
            if(compare(username,userName))
            {
                inFile.close();
                break;
            }       
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
}
}

void loadBeneficiary(char * userName)
{

int i = 0;
ifstream inFile;
string line;
inFile.open(FILE_NAME);

if (inFile.is_open()) {
    while (getline(inFile, line)) {
        stringstream ss(line);
        string value;
        while (getline(ss, value, ',')) {
            if (i == 0) {
                strcpy(b_username, value.c_str());
                i = 1;
            }
            else if (i == 1) {
                strcpy(b_pin, value.c_str());
                i = 2;
            }
            else if (i == 2) {
                b_balance = atof(value.c_str());
                i = 0;
            }   
            if(strcmp(b_username, userName)){
                inFile.close();
                break;
            }   
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
}
}

void login()
{
char tempName[50];
char tempPin[5];
cout << "\n\nEnter user name: ";
cin.getline(tempName, sizeof(tempName));
if (checkAccountExists(tempName)) {
    cout << "\n\nEnter user pin: ";
    cin.getline(tempPin,sizeof(tempPin));
    loadAccount(tempName);
    if (compare(tempPin, pin)) {
        cout << "\n\nLog in successfull!";
        cout << "\n\nPress any key to continue...";
        _getch();
        menuScreen();
    }else {
        cout << "User name or pin incorrect!";
        _getch();
    }
}
else {
    cout << "\n\nRecord not found. Press any key to continue...";
    _getch();
}

}

void checkBalance()
{
system("cls");
cout << "\n\n\tUser name = " << username;
cout << "\n\n\tBalance = " << balance;
_getch();
}

bool compare(char * msg1, char * msg2){
int count = 0;
int size = sizeof(msg1);
if(sizeof(msg2) == size){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(msg1[i]==msg2[i]){
            count++;
        }
    }
    if(count == size)
        return true;
}

return false;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

mainScreen();
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

**TXT FILE**

```
jhon,5155,99999.99
bot,4414,232323
theta,2111,34234
```

Comment: You need to learn how to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Perhaps [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) too.

Comment: I assume most of the standard library is also not permitted since you seem to be avoiding it.

Comment: "File handling for binary is easy" -- not at all; there are serious potential problems there. That's why text files are used so often.

Comment: Also, ***use*** the standard functions! They are optimized and can sometimes even be inlined, if it's performance you're worried about (*don't worry about it!*). They also make the code cleaner, more readable, and most importantly more *maintainable!* Then you mention something about a "semantic error", what do you mean by that? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  What I mean by semantic error is that I'm not getting the expected results. I expect the program by the logic I wrote to work fine but it's producing unexpected results. If it picks up username it won't pick up pin from the .txt file correctly.

Comment: Then perhaps you should read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert. One of the best ways to solve problems like this is with a *debugger*. Another good thing to think about is *simplicity*. As an example, instead of your current loop for parsing a line, use three separate and `getline` calls, one after the other. It's simpler, easier to read and understand, and since it's simpler there will be less chances of bugs in the code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude could you please explain your approach with `getline` in terms of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding how to simplify the reading loop, how about something like

```
while (getline(inFile, line)) {
    stringstream ss(line);
    string value;

    getline(ss, value, ',');
    string name = value;

    getline(ss, value, ',')
    string pin = value;

    getline(ss, value)
    double balance = stod(value);

    // Now use the name, pin and balance some way...
}
```

For when you only need the name you don't need to have the second and third `getline` call, just the first.

Also consider using *structures* to store the name, pin and balance, and then having a [container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) (for example a [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)) to stor the structures.

Also in the name of simplicity I suggest you read the file *only once*. Then loop over the vector to find the data you need.

Comment: I have one other version of this program in OOP C++ and using vectors. I load all the data to vector and manipulate that. But do you think it's good idea to do so? Is it a good practice to load whole data into memory or search through file each time?

Comment: It's good practice to load the whole file into memory if it fits, and either makes the code simpler or you need the extra speed. It's good practice to scan the file if it doesn't fit in memory, or you have limited memory better used for something else, or it makes the code simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative without using `stringstream`

```
while(getline(inFile,line,',')){

        strcpy(username, line.c_str());

        getline(inFile,line,',');
        strcpy(pin, line.c_str());

        getline(inFile,line,'\n');
        balance = atof(line.c_str());

        if(compare(username,userName)){
            inFile.close();
            break;
        }else 
            continue;

    }
```

Comment: Why are you mixing C-style strings and C++ strings? Why are you using globals for values you'll immediately overwrite (or indeed at all)?

Comment: @Useless I know it is insecure to do it this way. But you can't use .txt file for actual program like this either hence It's just for learning purposes.

Comment: Text files are used for plenty of actual programs, as configuration or other input. Just using `std::string` everywhere instead of mixing C++ strings, char arrays, `strcpy(...)`, `c_str()` etc. isn't insecure (well, it may be, but that's not my objection). It's just ugly and over-complicated. It's _harder_ to do this than to just use `std::string` everywhere, and I don't see any benefit outweighing the extra complexity.

Comment: I agree with you. I used `char array` so that I can compare` names` and `pin` `char` to `char`  in `compare(char*,char*)` but even after using that lets suppose I have two names to compare I won't succeed  with John and Johnn/Joh.